# Can CQEngine query an object inside another object

Tags: java, cqengine

Does anyone know if CQEngine can query objects with in other objects? I would like to be able to query users, orders and products.

Can this be done with CQEngine or would I need to flatten the objects?

```
public class User {
    public List<Orders> orders;
}

public class Orders {
    public List<Products> products; 
}

public class Products {
    public String name;
}
```

Comment: @npgall can you look into my another question related above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415936/cqengine-query-nested-object-using-parser-retrieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you just need to define a CQEngine attribute which will *return the values from the nested objects you want to search*.

For example, this attribute will retrieve the names of each Product, which is contained in the Orders, which were placed by a particular User.

```java
static final Attribute<User, String> PRODUCT_NAMES_ORDERED = new MultiValueAttribute<User, String>() {
    public Iterable<String> getValues(User user, QueryOptions queryOptions) {
        return user.orders.stream()
                .map(order -> order.products).flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(product -> product.name)::iterator;
    }
};
```

You could optionally add an index on this attribute, to accelerate queries on it.

Here's an example which sets up an `IndexedCollection` of Users, where each user has a number of Orders, and each order has a number of Products. The products are snacks you might find at a cinema. It searches the collection for users who ordered a "Snickers Bar".

```java
package com.googlecode.cqengine.examples.nestedobjects;

import com.googlecode.cqengine.*;
import com.googlecode.cqengine.attribute.*;
import com.googlecode.cqengine.query.option.QueryOptions;
import java.util.*;
import static com.googlecode.cqengine.query.QueryFactory.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

public class NestedObjectsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = new Order(asList(new Product("Diet Coke"), new Product("Snickers Bar")));
        Order order2 = new Order(singletonList(new Product("Sprite")));
        User user1 = new User(1, asList(order1, order2));

        Order order3 = new Order(asList(new Product("Sprite"), new Product("Popcorn")));
        User user2 = new User(2, singletonList(order3));

        Order order4 = new Order(singletonList(new Product("Snickers Bar")));
        User user3 = new User(3, singletonList(order4));

        IndexedCollection<User> users = new ConcurrentIndexedCollection<>();
        users.addAll(asList(user1, user2, user3));

        users.retrieve(equal(PRODUCT_NAMES_ORDERED, "Snickers Bar")).forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.userId));
        // ...prints 1, 3
    }

}
```

BTW I'm the author of CQEngine, and you can find the complete source for this example on the [CQEngine site](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine/blob/master/code/src/test/java/com/googlecode/cqengine/examples/nestedobjects/NestedObjectsExample.java). (I have just added this as a new example!)

Comment: That is actually amazing. It has cut my project dev time in half. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!